# Mobx React `autorun` called more times on every change

Tags: mobx, mobx-react-lite

I've setup a simple app store with a single numeric value, which I increment on every button click. My UI is simple: a single app `<div>` which contains a `MyChild` component that renders the number next to an increment button.

The app's `autorun` seems to behave correctly BUT every time I increment the value, `MyChild`'s `autorun` fire extra times i.e. on page load it fires once. If I click the button, it fires twice. I click again, it fires 3 times, and so on. I expect that on every increment, `autorun` would fire once. What am I missing here?

Code is available on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-margulis-oeh0qp?file=/src/App.js)
Here it is here as well:

```
import "./styles.css";

import * as React from "react";
import { observer } from "mobx-react-lite";
import { action, autorun, makeAutoObservable } from "mobx";

class AppStore {
  v;
  constructor() {
    this.v = 0;
    makeAutoObservable(this);
  }
}
const appStore = new AppStore();

const MyChild = observer(() => {
  console.log("MyChild render", appStore.v);

  autorun(() => { // <------------------------ this gets fired extra times
    console.log("mychild autorun " + appStore.v);
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "lightBlue" }}>
      mychild {appStore.v}
      {": "}
      <button
        onClick={action(() => {
          appStore.v += 1;
        })}
      >
        INC
      </button>
    </div>
  );
});

export default observer(function App() {
  console.log("app render");

  autorun(() => {
    console.log("app autorun " + appStore.v);
  });

  return (
    <>
      <div style={{ backgroundColor: "gray", padding: "10px" }}>
        main
        <MyChild />
      </div>
    </>
  );
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I have found the reason (I'm new to Mobx-React, guess I should have figured it out)
According to [this tip](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html#useeffect), I need to setup `autorun` inside a `useEffect` that happens on first render. I changed all my autoruns to:

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    return autorun(...);
}, []);
```

and now they get fired once every render.

Comment: You forgot to clean autorun on unmount. This could cause memory leaks.

Comment: I've updated the answer to include dispose